# The While Loop PHP

Tags: php

why this code is output of 8?

```
<?php
    $i = 1;
    while ($i <= 7) {
        $i++;
    }
  echo "The value is $i <br />";
?>
```

but when you put this code on open and close parenthesis
echo $i;

the output is

12345678

Please Explain how.. Thanks!

Comment: because  `echo ` executed in the last after while loop execution and that's why only the last incremented value is shown which is 8. it's the most basic thing which a beginner can tell also

Comment: $i =7 -> while is true -> $i++ -> Output

Comment: Think of the way it executes the last loop this way. If $i=7 then increment $i by 1 and echo $i. It will give you 8.  Otherwise if you want it to output echo "The value is $i <br />" ; in sequence put it between while ($i <= 7) {  and $i++;

Comment: i knew it! 

x=0
(0<=7(true) x++) (x=1) 
(1<=7(true) x++) (x=2) 
(2<=7(true) x++) (x=3) 
(3<=7(true) x++) (x=4) 
(4<=7(true) x++) (x=5) 
(5<=7(true) x++) (x=6) 
(6<=7(true) x++) (x=7) 
(7<=7(true) x++) (x=8) 
so the answer is 8

Answer (score 2):

I'm struggling to understand what you mean by:-

> but when you put this on open and close parenthesis "echo "

With that said however I can certainly help explain why the output is 8.

Your counter starts at 1 (`$i = 1`). You then run a while loop that checks if the value of your counter is less than or equal to 7. You're incrementing the counter by 1 on each iteration of the loop.

When `$i` equals 7 the loop runs again (`<=`); `$i` is incremented to 8.

Answer (score 1):

You made a while function in which you add a condition to run function until the $i is less than or equal to 7 ( while ($i <= 7) ). So when $i ==7 the fuction run again then the $i ==8 now your condition is wrong so he break the loop and output you 8.

Answer (score 0):

Basically in your first case the `echo` is executed after the loop and only once. There the value is 8, hence the result you observe.

By putting the `echo` in the loop, it is executed for each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

7<7 is false but 7=7 is true, so your loop executes once again and the output is 8. Put echo in the while loop if you want to print each and every output of loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
while loop will execute when given condition is true. So here
```

- $i = 1; is less than or equal 7 so again loop. This time $i increased +1 
now, $i = 2 again condition is true,
now, $i = 3 again condition is true,
now, $i = 4 again condition is true,
now, $i = 5 again condition is true,
 - now, $i = 6 again condition is true,
now, $i = 7 again condition is true,
now, $i = 8 Here condition is False so loop is ended, So next line will be executed here $i value is 8. so you getting output is 8.